# Is using singleton pattern in angularjs a bad practise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, singleton, frontend

I have been coding in Angular JS for a while now. A friend of mine suggested me not to use singleton pattern in AngularJS, as it is a bad practise. I was totally unaware of that. Is it so?

Comment: Ask your friend for some github repository links to his angular applications so we can see how he develops without using singletons.

Comment: This is a question for your friend, not for SO.

Comment: So your friend doesn't use factories or services? Like to see how they get around using those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because services are singletons by design. Quote from the docs:

> Note: All services in Angular are singletons. That means that the injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The injector then caches the reference for all future needs.

Source: [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)